# JQuery Mobile .page() function causes infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, dhtml

I'm dynamically creating a listview with data from a AJAX response. It successfully creates the listview and populates it, but when i call JQM's .page() function on it, it seemingly goes into an infinite loop where the listview is appended forever.

Is this a bug in JQM or am I doing something wrong?

```
pageScript(function($context){
    $context.bind("pagecreate", function(event, ui){
        createMenu(); //function that deletes existing ul#menu and dynamically creates new one. 
        $('ul#menu').page(); //here's where it causes a problem
        $('#menu a').bind('click', function(){
            $.mobile.changePage($(this).attr("href"), {pageContainer: $("#primary-content"), transition: "fade", changeHash: false, reloadPage: true});
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

pageScript is a function that allows me to run page-level scripts when they are loaded by JQM. It's defined in the base template or index.html:

```
function pageScript(func) {
            var $context = $("div:jqmData(role='page'):last");
            func($context);
        };
```

Comment: .page() refreshes the page with jQM markup

Comment: it appears that you can't selectively use .page() on individual elements. it runs on "page" level and subsequently triggers the "pagecreate" event.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using `.page()` use `.trigger( "create" );`
jQuery Mobile team update: Week of July 18th http://jquerymobile.com/blog/