# How to refresh page on load finish JQuery Mobile?

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, button, onclick, page-refresh

I am making a JQuery Mobile PhoneGap Build app, I need the page to refresh or reload after being open. This page would open by link from the mainpage. I do this because for some reason when the link open from the mainpage none of the functions work when attached to a onclick or onmouseover button.

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery Mobile Page refresh mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663078/jquery-mobile-page-refresh-mechanism)

It looks like there is written mechanism of refreshing a page.