# How to complete reset a page in jQuery Mobile after submitting a form

Tags: jquery, forms, mobile, submit, reset

This is a trivial question but I can't find the answer.

This is the code I use to submit my form in jQuery mobile

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { // catch the form's submit event
    // Send data to server through ajax call
    // action is functionality we want to call and output - JSON is our data
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/db/ajax_insert_completed_quests.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        type: 'get',                   
        async: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(true); // This will show ajax spinner
        },
        complete: function() {
            // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg(); // This will hide ajax spinner
        },
        success: function (result) {

        },
        error: function (request,error) {
            // This callback function will trigger on unsuccessful action                
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
        }
    });                         
    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
});
```

So what do put in the success function? What I want to achieve is that the user stays on the form page, but that the page is basically refreshed, as if someone pushed F5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this function -

```
function refreshPage() {
    jQuery.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        reloadPage: true
    });
}
```

There are some other solutions to this, I found them here on stackoverflow - [jQuery Mobile Page refresh mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663078/jquery-mobile-page-refresh-mechanism)

[Reload the Same Page Without Blinking on jQuery Mobile](http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/29/reload-the-same-page-without-blinking-on-jquery-mobile/)

Have you considered manually setting your form values back to empty on the page?  This may be a more optimal solution.

Comment: The function didn't work but resetting the values back to empty using $(#form)[0].reset(); did.