# Updating the dynamic PHP in a jQuery Mobile site after updating the database

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, refresh

Let's say I have 2 pages in a jQuery Mobile website.

Page1 - shows data from a database using inline PHP.

Page2 - inserts new data into the database.

The problem is that page1 is not updated when going back, after page2 adds something to the database. I can get it updated by pressing F5, but how can I achieve the same update using jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're showing data in Page 1 using the `pageinit` event. This will fire only once and won't update your data every time you add new data.

You need to use `pagebeforeshow` event of Page 1 to get data from database. This way, new data will be brought every time, which is what you need. Here's a syntax :

```
 $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", "#page1", function() {
      //call to server
 });
```

If you're not using `pageinit`, you must be using `document.ready` event to get data. Well, thats the way thats done. You must not use `ready` with jquery mobile. DOM `ready` will initialize the whole document which will make the `ajax` page change feature of jQM pointless & useless.

Answer (score 1):

It was late last night and I missed that I should just get my inline php content using Ajax.

So this is how I solved it:

1. Moved everything contain dynamic content using PHP in a separate file.
2. Add an Ajax call to the bottom of the page that loads the PHP file as follows:

   ```
   $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function(){
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",        
            url: "includes/db/ajax_show_php_content.php",       
            success: function(html) {
               $("#page1").html(html); //Insert PHP content
           $("#page1").trigger('create'); //Apply jQuery Mobile style to it.
       });                 
   });
   ```

Thanks to @hungerpain and @anglinb for their help in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not extremely familiar with jQuery Moblie but here's what I found:

```
function refreshPage()
{
   jQuery.mobile.changePage(window.location.href, {
        allowSamePageTransition: true,
        transition: 'none',
        reloadPage: true
    });
}
```

I think the reloadPage to true should do the trick.

If that doesn't work, check out this answer: [jQuery Mobile Page refresh mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663078/jquery-mobile-page-refresh-mechanism)

Hope this helps!