# jQuery mobile on Android phone: pages rendered from brower's history are broken. How do I force a complete page rebuild?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile

All!

I have a perplexing problem that occurs only on some specific phones-- but they're the phones that my customer wants the app written for, so I need to deliver. :-/  The site that I am working on consists of fourteen jQuery mobile "pages", and two of them are exhibiting the following behavior:

I have an issue where pages being loaded from the browser's cache-- whether by pressing the browser's "back button" or simply reloading a page that has been previously rendered-- is broken:

While the page renders correctly, the bottom of the page is either "cut off" and can't be scrolled to, or a medium amount of "new" blank content is inserted at the bottom of the page.

When the latter occurs, the UI controls are "shifted" by the length of the new blank content compared to where the user was tapping: If an inch was "inserted" when the page is displayed for the second time, tapping on the screen triggers a click event in the location an inch "higher" on the page than where my finger touched the screen.

I will note that this problem appears to occur only on pages that have enough content to scroll off screen; pages that have small amounts of content do not suffer this problem.  There is no dynamic content being added to these pages.

It appears that once a page is created and then a different page is displayed, something breaks in the DOM when the previously-created page is redisplayed.

The mobile sites run perfectly in Chrome and Firefox on a PC; they manifest themselves only on certain Android phones.  One phone model that is giving me particular headaches is a Samsung SGH-I437P running Android 4.1.2.

I'm using the latest versions of jQuery-- rev 1.9.1 of jQuery, and 1.3.2 of jQuery mobile.

What I *think* I need to do is to tell jQuery to completely rebuild the page, but am unsure if this is even feasible, as the since the page has already been loaded into the DOM with all the jQuery mobile "embellishments"-- so there's no "bare-bones non-jQuery-mobile" HTML to rebuild the page with.

However, searching for page rebuilding / reloading hasn't turned up any concrete hits-- there [was a way to do this with older versions of jQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663078/jquery-mobile-page-refresh-mechanism), but this does not work for the latest version.

Has anyone else experienced this behavior and know how to counteract it?  My team of two have been focused on this for weeks to no avail.

---

Comment: It looks like a css issue with certain phones/browsers. Try `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () { $(this).trigger('pagecreate'); });`.

Comment: Thanks, Omar, but when I attempted this all I get is an empty white page. :-(