# jquery mobile page refresh or table refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile

I've got a jquery mobile application with a page that contains a table. This table is database driven and it has some up/down buttons to control the order. Got the buttons to work, but the table doesn't reflect the changes that were made. The suggestion at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663078/jquery-mobile-page-refresh-mechanism) almost works. It refreshes the list correctly, but the buttons don't work. I see a page gets added to the DOM, and I know the tags in this page probably share the same IDs which could be causing an issue, but I can't think of a way to get around this.

```
ajax call here
$.mobile.changePage(
    window.location.href,
    {
        allowSamePageTransition : true,
        transition              : 'none',
        showLoadMsg             : false,
        reloadPage              : true
    }
);
```

Comment: You'll be wanting to add some code my brother!! Otherwise this will get closed down

Comment: @JamieHutber did you mean code? I've added the code I used to refresh the page

Comment: The problem with `reloadPage` is it duplicates the same page. Listeners are attached to old page not new one, that's why buttons don't work.

Comment: @Omar how else do I get the display to refresh?