# jquery mobile not loading objects?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I can't get this to load on consecutive pages:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.container').find('img').each(function(){
    var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
    $(this).addClass(imgClass);
  })
})
```

I recently read [JQuery Mobile .page() function causes infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624664/jquery-mobile-page-function-causes-infinite-loop) but I'm not sure where documentation is for `.mobile` or `.page`.

Comment: could not get the following to work on pages after the initial . i'm using a next|previous feature (pagination) and the following only occurs on the initial page. tried pagecreate but did not work

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).load(function(){
   $('.container').find('img').each(function(){
     var imgClass = (this.width/this.height > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
     $(this).addClass(imgClass);
   })
})

Comment: In your comment you are nesting two event handlers deep (and you haven't quite hit the right event). You only need one, check-out my answer below. Also, `$(document).ready()` is not the same as binding to the `pagecreate` event for a pseudo-page in jQuery Mobile.

Answer (score 1):

You are binding to the `window.load` event which only fires on the initial page load. In jQuery Mobile, each time you navigate to another page it is brought into the DOM via AJAX, so no full-page-refresh occurs. That is why you need to bind to a `page-event` using `.delegate()`. `page-events` are triggered on the specific `data-role="page"` elements that it relates to. For example, if you have a page with an id of `some_id` you can bind to the `pagecreate` event for that page by doing this:

```
$(document).delegate('#some_id', 'pagecreate', function(){
    alert('Alright, it worked!');
});
```

If you want to bind an event to all pseudo-pages in your site then this selector will work:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="page"]', 'pagecreate', function(){
    var $page = $(this);
    $page.find('.container').find('img').each(function(){
        var $image = $(this),
            imgClass = ($image.width()/$image.height() > 1) ? 'wide' : 'tall';
        $image.addClass(imgClass);
    })
});
```

This block of code does not need to be placed in a `document.ready` or `window.load` event handler, it can just be included globally.

Check-out this documentation on jQuery Mobile events: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/events.html

To learn more about `$.mobile` check-out this page and the different functions you can use: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/methods.html

`.page()` has beed depreciated in favor of `trigger('create')`. This is how you initialize any jQuery Mobile widget.

Comment: thank you jasper. especially for where that documentation is ;-)

Comment: @RafaelDaCosta You're welcome, I noticed you haven't selected any accepted answers to your questions, you may want to check-out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: @RafaelDaCosta The fix appears to be working on my end, the `tall` class is added to the `tea-obreht-tigers-wife-by-beowulf-sheehan.jpg` image. What else isn't working? Btw, you mobile site is returning five 404 errors for some CSS style-sheets that are not in the `mobile/css/` directory.

Comment: i tried to vote up but got this message 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation' ;-( you were very helpful