# jquery mobile change navibar from width

Tags: jquery-mobile, width, navbar

How to change navbar in jQuery Mobile from width like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f6Hq7.png)?

In m.IKEA it's make:

```
<div data-role="header" id="ikea-homeheader" data-backbtn="false">
    <div id="ikea-navbar" data-role="headerbar" data-moreListId="#ikea-more-list">
        <ul>            
            <li class="ikea-navbar-item "><a href="/se/sv/" >Hem</a></li>
            <li class="ikea-navbar-item "><a href="/se/sv/catalog/functional/" >Sortiment</a></li>
            <li class="ikea-navbar-item "><a href="/se/sv/shoppinglist/" rel="nofollow">Inkopslista</a></li>
            <li class="ikea-navbar-item ikea-navbar-item-active"><a href="/se/sv/stores/" >Varuhus</a></li>

            <li class="ui-headerbar-more-item" data-role="headerbar-more-item"><a data-role="popupbutton" data-popup-content="more-item-popup" ><div class="ikea-navbar-more-image"></div></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>


<div data-role="popup" id="more-item-popup">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" id="ikea-more-list">
    </ul>
    <div data-role="popup-cancel-button">
        <div data-role="button" data-theme="c">Cancel</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

But how it's work I don't understand.

In my jQuery mobile 1.0.1 It's don't work ...

What's **data-role="headerbar"**, **data-moreListId**, **data-role="headerbar-more-item"** ?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Your images appear to be different sizes, that's all.

Comment: Navbar change when you change the width of the screen. I can not understand how to make the trigger to the width.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to refresh the width on orientation change, you could try reapplying jqm styling/formatting using this command:

```
$("#your-jqm-page").page();
```

.page() refreshes the page with jQM markup.  You may also have to try the `.trigger("create")` method as discussed here: [JQuery Mobile .page() function causes infinite loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6624664/jquery-mobile-page-function-causes-infinite-loop)

As for your other new questions, those `data` attributes look like elements added by the jqm framework after the page is initialized.

**UPDATE**

If you are trying to detect when a browser has resized, use a function like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

  // this is whatever size you would like to make the change on, in pixels
  var minimumPreferredSize = 600;

  if ($(window).width() < minimumPreferredSize) {
     $("#Varuhus").html("...");
  }
  else
  {
     $("#Varuhus").html("Varuhus");
  }
});
```

This solution assumes your `a` tag has an `id` of Varuhus.

This solution was made possible by this other post: [Detect when a window is resized using JavaScript ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2996431/javascript-detect-when-a-window-is-resized)

Hope this helps!

Comment: How will work .trigger("create") with change width a window ?

Comment: @TITAN I would like to help but I do not understand what you mean by change width of a window.  You mean when orientation changes or do you mean a full browser running on a desktop/laptop PC?

Comment: full browser running on a desktop/laptop PC? - yes, not only.

Comment: Please see updated answer, this may be the solution you were looking for.